# Wordpress Rest Api ionic app loading

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, cordova, rest, ionic-framework

I'm developing a Wordpress Ionic application using the Wordpress REST API and Jetpack. I followed a tutorial [Hybrid Mobile Application with Ionic/Cordova](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbopML8dnqg), but ran into an ugly problem. When I enter my REST API link in `$http.get()` and try it in my browser it keeps loading like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/gallery/6lqUK2M/]

On the other hand, the [Freshy-Pressed Api](http://But%20when%20I%20but%20freshly-press%20api%20it%20works) works, though I don't know why.

Here is the HTML and JavaScript I'm using:

```js
var FPApp = angular.module("FPApp", ["ionic"]);

FPApp.service("FPSvc", ["$http", "$rootScope", FPSvc]);

FPApp.controller("FPCtrl", 
    ["$scope", "$sce", 
     "$ionicLoading", "$ionicListDelegate", "$ionicPlatform",
     "FPSvc", FPCtrl]);

function FPCtrl($scope, $sce, $ionicLoading, $ionicListDelegate, $ionicPlatform, FPSvc) {

    $ionicLoading.show({template: "Loading blogs..."});

    $scope.deviceReady = false;

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.deviceReady = true;
        });
    });

    $scope.blogs = [];
    $scope.params = {};

    $scope.$on("FPApp.blogs", function(_, result) {
        result.posts.forEach(function(b) {
            $scope.blogs.push({
                name: b.author.name,
                avatar_URL: b.author.avatar_URL,
                title: $sce.trustAsHtml(b.title),
                URL: b.URL,

                featured_image: b.post_thumbnail.URL
            });
        });

        $scope.params.before = result.date_range.oldest;

        $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        $scope.$broadcast("scroll.refreshComplete");
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        FPSvc.loadBlogs($scope.params);
    }
    $scope.reload = function() {
        $scope.blogs = [];
        $scope.params = {};
        FPSvc.loadBlogs();
    }

    $scope.show = function($index) {
        cordova.InAppBrowser.open($scope.blogs[$index].URL, "_blank", "location=no");
    }
    $scope.share = function($index) {
        $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();
        window.socialmessage.send({
            url: $scope.blogs[$index].URL
        });
    }

}

function FPSvc($http, $rootScope) {
    this.loadBlogs = function(params) {
        $http.get("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/100060382/posts/", {
                params: params})
            .success(function(result) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("FPApp.blogs", result);
            });
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="FPApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!--Setup Cordova-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!--Setup Ionic-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--Setup Application-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="FPCtrl">
    <ion-pane>
<div class="bar bar-header bar-energized">
  <h1 class="title">ZahranPress</h1>
</div>
        <ion-content class="background">
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull" on-refresh="reload()">
        </ion-refresher>
            <div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="b in blogs">
                <div class="item item-avatar">
                    <img data-ng-src="{{b.avatar_URL}}" alt="">
                    <h2 data-ng-bind-html="b.title"></h2>
                    <p> {{ b.name }} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item item-body">
                    <img data-ng-if="b.featured_image" data-ng-src="{{ b.featured_image }}" alt="" class="full-image">

                </div>
                <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
                         <a class="tab-item" data-ng-click="show($index)">
                       <i class="icon ion-ios-book"></i>
                       Read
                   </a>
                    <a class="tab-item" data-ng-click="share($index)">
                        <i class="icon ion-share"></i>
                        Share
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" ng-if="deviceReady"></ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you *expect* it to look?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford the loading should disappear